# Update user meta from frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have a following form for my wordpress site:

```
<?php
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();  
 ?>

<div class="rh_contact_form">    
    <div class="mdl-textfield rhc_phone_number_class">  
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
            <?php echo '<input type="text" id="rhc_phone" name="rhc_phone" placeholder="Phone number" value="' .$current_user -> rh_phone. '"/>' ;?>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="rhc_phone" name="rhc_phone" placeholder="Phone number" value=""/>
         <?php } ?>                                             
    </div>

    <div class="rhc_ask">   
        <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "3" id="rhc_ask" name="rhc_ask" placeholder="Ask seller"></textarea>           
    </div>  
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</div>
```

So, there are two user metakeys:  `rh_phone`, and `rh_ask`

How do I update the metavalue for these two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add something similar to this inside your forms processing function. Also call the "current user" inside of that function, or pass the ID through a hidden field in your form.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$rh_phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['rh_phone']);
$rh_ask= sanitize_text_field($_POST['rh_ask']);

if( isset($rh_phone) ){
    update_post_meta($current_user, 'rh_phone', $rh_phone);
}
if( isset($rh_ask) ){
    update_post_meta($current_user, 'rh_ask', $rh_ask);
}
```

You could find more info on update_post_meta() here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta. I hope that helps.